# How can i open facebook when facebook app is not logged in my iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad

If facebook application is logged, page will be opened when executing this code and else if i am disconnected from facebook app on my iPhone when executing this code, i will be redirected to the facebook app to login then after connecting app facebook is no redirected to the page !

```
NSURL *fbNativeAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://page/yourPageIDHere"]
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbNativeAppURL]
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 they have removed the redirecting to settings page . Me also tried a lot but not succeeded. So I have used FBGraph api for login .